# Jdbi string template engine conditional with expression

Tags: java, stringtemplate-4, jdbi3

I'm trying to use jdbi string template engine with an expression in an if condition.
I tried different versions:

```
<if(expr(range.equals(\"xxx\")))>
<if(expr(range==\"xxx\"))>
<if(expr(range=\"xxx\"))>
<if(range==\"xxx\")>
```

but I haven't found a way to use the if condition with a logical expression instead of a boolean value.
Is it possible a such behaviour or I have to pass N boolean variable to my dao method?

Comment: hey did you found out any solution?

Comment: @HimanshuJotwani no way, I was forced to use booleans